# Create a list of column names corresponding to row names based on value and append in dataframe

Tags: r

I have following dataframe:

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  
R1  1   0   0   1   5  
R2  0   1   5   8   3   
R3  5   8   0   6   0
```

Now I want the result in following form

```
R1 C2,C3
R2 C1
R3 C3,C5
```

ie colnames of all the values >0 of particular row along with row name in data frame.

Comment: `which(mydf == 0, arr.ind = TRUE)` might also be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can loop through the rows with `apply`, get the `names` that correspond to values that are 0 and `paste`

```
data.frame(col1 = apply(df1, 1, FUN = function(x) toString(names(x)[x==0])))
```